# ERROR:The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed. Scala XML.loadString()

Tags: xml, scala, user-defined-functions

I know this question asked alot. But I am not able to find relevant information.

I am passing a string to userdefined function in scala.
The string looks like this

```
<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.</p>

<p>This is my code:</p>

 <pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;
this.Opacity = trans;
</code></pre>

<p>When I build the application, it gives the following error:</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'.</p>
</blockquote>

<p>I tried using <code>trans</code> and <code>double</code> but then the 
control doesn't work. This code worked fine in a past VB.NET project. </p>
,While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?
```

My user defined function looks like this

```
    case class bodyresults(text:String,code:String)
    val bodyudf = udf{ (body: String)  =>
     //Appending body tag explicitly to the xml before parsing  
    val xmlElems = xml.XML.loadString(s"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-
8"?> <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> <body> ${body} </body>""")
    // extract the code inside the req
    val code = (xmlElems \\ "body" \\ "pre" \\ "code").text
    val text = (xmlElems \\ "body").text.replaceAll(s"${code}" ,"" )
    bodyresults(text, code)
    }
```

It caused an error nbsp is defined but not declared. so I appended . now its causing

```
Error:The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A proper entity declaration in the internal subset of the DTD (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-doctypedecl) would be `<!DOCTYPE body [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>` if I remember that correctly. Whether the XML parser used by Scala supports I don't know.

Comment: Thank you @Martin its worked.